# Not test found with gradle and intellij only when press rerun failed tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

When I run a test and the test fail and I press the button `Rerun failed tests` I get the following error `Test events where not received`  `No tests found for given includes`, but is weird because the test just run and failded, and when I try to rerun it with the button rerun test doesn't work.

I'm using `gradle 6.8.1` `intellij idea community edition 2020.3.2` and `spring boot 2.4.2`

this is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

this is my test

```
package com.example.map.struc.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest
class MapStrucExampleApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    void name() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue for the Rerun Failed Tests action when Gradle is used to run tests: [IDEA-194699](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194699).

Comment: they said that is closed, that if you have junit5.3 it would work, but I still have the problem, and I have junit5.7